# interrupt main Thread from user thread using object class methods in java

Tags: java

```
    class A
        implements Runnable
    {
        int time;

        A( int time )
        {
            this.time = time;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
            {
                System.out.println( Thread.currentThread().getName() );
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep( time );
                }
                catch ( Exception e )
                {
                    System.out.println( e );
                }
                ;
            }
        }
    }
    class Check
    {
        public static void main( String args[] )
            throws Exception, Throwable
        {
            Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
            A a1 = new A( 200, t );
            A a2 = new A( 100, t );
            A a3 = new A( 500, t );
            Thread t1 = new Thread( a1 );
            Thread t2 = new Thread( a2 );
            Thread t3 = new Thread( a3 );
            t1.start();
            t2.start();
            t3.start();
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep( 5000 );
            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
            }
            ;// => i have to interrupt this sleep.
            System.out.println( "Main Thread's rest of the code" );
        }
    }
```

I want to interrupt the main Thread's sleep once when all the user threads are compeleted. If main Thread awakens before user thread completes then it must execute simultaneously along with other user threads.
p.s: This can be done with Object classes in java. So give me some suggestions using that.

Comment: Do you need to do it like this, as opposed to using something like a CountdownLatch?

Answer (score 2):

Using an ExecutorService would be much simpler, but assuming you need to use Threads directly....

All you need do is

```
t1.join();
t2.join();
t3.join();
```

to wait for all the thread to finish.

You can optimise this a little by using run()

```
t1.start();
t2.start();
t3.run(); // use the current thread

t1.join();
t2.join();
// only need to join two threads.
```

> if main thread wakes up early then i have to perform main thread's rest of the code simultaneously along with the user threads..

Say you want to wait for the background thread but no more than 5 seconds (I can't imagine why you would do this but ...)

```
long end = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000;
t1.join(Math.max(1, end - System.currentTimeMillis()));
t2.join(Math.max(1, end - System.currentTimeMillis()));
t3.join(Math.max(1, end - System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

The main thread will wait up to 5 seconds, finishing early if the threads are done, but will give up waiting if not.

To do similarly with an ExecutorService you can do

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
es.submit(new A(200));
es.submit(new A(100));
es.submit(new A(500));

es.shutdown();
es.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: but if main thread wakes up early then i have to perform main thread's rest of the code simultaneously along with the user threads.. In this case, main thread will always wait till the user threads are done.

Comment: @KarthikeyanGopall I have added a solution to wake up after 5 seconds if the thread have not finished.

Comment: @KarthikeyanGopall Also added a solution using an ExecutorService which might be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using something like an `ExecutorService`. You could do it something like this:

```
ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutorService(...);
executorService.submit(new A(200));
executorService.submit(new A(100));
executorService.submit(new A(500));

executorService.shutdown();
executorService.awaitTermination(/* some timeout */);

System.out.println("Main Thread's rest of the code");
```

This avoids you actually having to think about coordinating the execution of the individual threads, and makes handling of grotty edge cases (e.g. what if one thread never terminates) much easier.

Comment: but if main thread wakes up early then i have to perform main thread's rest of the code simultaneously along with the user threads.. 
In this case, main thread will always wait till the user threads are done.

Comment: You can always make the timeout `Long.MAX_VALUE`, then it's reasonably unlikely to wake up until you want it to.

Comment: The other thing to bear in mind is that if you are waiting for /something/ to interrupt a particular thread, then /something/ might, i.e. any other thread in the JVM which happens to have a reference to your thread, not just the ones you are waiting for. You'd have to check that all the threads are completed in that case too.

Comment: how to use Long.MAX_VALUE in this case?

Comment: `executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`

Comment: yes. that is wat i exactly want. I want to wake the main thread if all the user threads are done if it's still in sleep state. Other wise no issues.

Comment: give me some suggestions with object class methods. pls